# How to sum cells in a column per id in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to Sql server. the sum(datediff(x,y,z)) is giving the sum of both a1 and a2 whereas I want the sum separate for a1 and a2. I dont know how to group it per id. I know that sum will return the sum of both but I want to know how can I separate them.

```
select email,
    sum(datediff(day, x, y))
from abc
where users.id ='a1'
    or users.id='a2'
group by email, users.id

email|datex|datey|
a1   |1    |2
a1   |1    |3
a1   |2    |5
a2   |2    |7
a2   |3    |7
a2   |1    |8
```

So what I need

```
email|diff
a1   |4
a2   |6
```

Comment: No, it should give the sum per group. Your query as posted will not compile since you are not grouping by `email` but are including it in the select.  I suggest you post your actual query instead of a mock-up.

Comment: sorry, it will be against ethics but I added email in group by

Comment: your answer of above query is not correct the answer should be a1 = 6 and a2 = 16 if i am not wrong

Comment: What is the question here?  Your query gives you the expected results, though they are 6 and 16 as @ArunGairola said, not 4 and 6.  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90c0d/1

Answer (score 0):

I stored the output as view without sum and then selected the sum group by id.

```
Create view vwTesting
AS    
select email,
    datediff(day, x, y) as diff
    from abc
    where users.id ='a1'
    or users.id='a2'
    group by email, users.id
```

In the second part

```
Select email, sum(diff) from vwTesting group by email
```

Answer (score 0):

### This is the query for your output

```
select  email, sum(datediff(day,datex,datey)) as dd  from (
select 'a1' as email, 1 as datex ,2 as datey
union all 
select 'a1' as email, 1 as datex ,3 as datey
union all 
select 'a1' as email, 2 as datex ,5 as datey
union all 
select 'a2' as email, 2 as datex ,7 as datey
union all 
select 'a2' as email, 3 as datex ,7 as datey
union all 
select 'a2' as email, 1 as datex ,8 as datey
) X 
GRoup BY email
```